# MySQL update date field in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction] format

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I'm using MySQL. I created a table with column `LAST_SELECTED datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`. When record is getting inserted, I get the timestamp with 6 digit microsecond precision (`2017-10-08 08:06:53.812136`). But when column is updated through code (MyBatis - ORM), I'm loosing the microsecond level precision (`2017-10-08 08:13:42.000000`). Is there any way to achieve the true value of the date (microsecond level precision -  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]`)?

Below is the query which is executed via MyBatis-

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET MYTABLE.LAST_SELECTED = current_timestamp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the "6" in as an argument:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
    SET MYTABLE.LAST_SELECTED = current_timestamp(6) ;
```

You can experience this directly yourself by running:

```
select date_format(current_timestamp(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'),
       date_format(current_timestamp(6), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')
```